# Cant play Multiplayer in bowmasters (iOS device)

Tags: bowmasters

I can't play Multiplayer in this Game AT ALL! When I tap online it says to choose my character so I choose it and then it says I can't play right now! (iOS 10.2,iPhone 6s)